# Ingress-NGINX Redirects

Tags: kubernetes, redirect, http-headers, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to solve an issue where I'm trying to do a redirect, but when I check my network tab, it shows multiple redirects happening.

What I want to achieve is that when I type in "example.com/about" into the URL bar, it should redirect to "https://www.example.com/about".

What's actually happening is

- redirect 1 = http://example.com/about => https://example.com/about
- redirect 2 = https://example.com/about => https://www.example.com/about
- redirect 3 = https://www.example.com/about => https://www.example.com/about/

I'm really not sure about why the last one is doing another redirect for a trailing slash, but I want redirects 1 and 2 to happen in a single redirect.

Current config:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-service-ingress
  namespace: my-ns
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "64m"
    nginx.org/client-max-body-size: "64m"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
      add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
      add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
      add_header X-Download-Options noopen;
      add_header Referrer-Policy origin-when-cross-origin;
      more_clear_headers 'X-Powered-By';
      expires 0;
spec:
  rules:
    - host: "www.example.com"
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/"
            backend:
              service:
                name: my-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Other options I've tried include:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-service
  namespace: my-ns
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "64m"
    nginx.org/client-max-body-size: "64m"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      if ($host = "example.com") {
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
      }
spec:
  rules:
    - host: "www.example.com"
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/"
            backend:
              service:
                name: my-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

I've also tried some configuration snippets using the x-forwarded-proto header since my load balancer supports it. But I still keep seeing multiple redirects.

Thanks for helping me look into this.